# Groovy - ArrayList remove brackets

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I've parsed the Below Json file and retrieve the username value.

```
"LogInFunctionTest": [
    {
      "TestCaseID": "Login-TC_02",
      "TestScenario": "Negative Case - Login with unregistered username and Password",
      "TestData": [
        {
          "UserName": "usernameX",
          "Password": "passwordX"
        }
      ]
```

Using the below code to retrieve the `UserName` Value.

```
def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parse(new File(fileName))
def testDataItem = InputJSON.LogInFunctionTest.find { it.TestCaseID == Login-TC_02 }.TestData.UserName
```

Output - `[usernameX]`

After this, I want to remove the brackets from the above.

```
'Remove brackets from arraylist'
        testDataItem = testDataItem.substring(1, testDataItem.length() - 1)
```

I'm getting the below exception

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.length() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: last(), last(), init(), init(), get(int), get(int)
```

Anyone guide us on how to remove the brackets from the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testDataItem` is a list of UserNames as `TestData` contains a list

That's why when it's displayed to you, it has `[]` round it...

If you just want the first one in the list, then you can do:

```
def testDataItem = InputJSON
    .LogInFunctionTest
    .find { it.TestCaseID == 'Login-TC_02' }
    .TestData
    .UserName
    .first()
```

(ie: put a call to `first()` at the end)

Obviously, if there's two of them, you'll only be getting the first one

You could also get the first one with `.UserName[0]`, but `.first()` is more descriptive

Answer (score 1):

```
testDataItem = testDataItem.get(0)
```

might do the job.

Looks like you're reading a list of Strings, not a String.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the above code return "sername" instead of "usernameX" so i changed the position "testDataItem = testDataItem.getAt(0).substring(0, testDataItem.getAt(0).length() - 0)"

Comment: Yes, that's right, the whole substring is unnecessary!

Answer (score 0):

Technically you referred to 'TestData' as a List with the brackets above so proper reference should be:

```
TestData[0].UserName
```

... or since it's all contained in the 'LogInFunctionTest' List:

```
LogInFunctionTest[0].TestData[0].UserName
```

That is if you are not going to loop/iterate through them.